# Various token errors in c++ code?

Tags: c++

So I'm doing an assignment for my intro c++ course and I continue to receive token errors like expected '}' at the end of input and expected ';' before '{' token. I'm suppose to make this code be able to store a graph and I'm taking it step by step, still tryna figure out, but cant get past these errors. (rookie). If there is anything I can do please criticize me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node                        
{                                 //currently private members
 int number;
 T value;

 public:

 Node()                       //constructors never have a return type, constructor name is same as class name
 {
     number=1;               //initial value of number
     T replace;
     value= replace;
 }
};

template <class T>
class Edge                       
{
Node<T> edge_one;           //Two data members of type Node<T>, one member    called edge_one and another called edge_two
Node<T> edge_two;
};





template <class T>
class Graph                      //only storing two data using free store and implementing seven functions
{

Node<T>* v= new Node<T>;           //using pointer and new to store data
Edge<T>* e= new Edge<T>; 

 public:

 Graph()
 {

 GetAllVertices(v)
 {
vector<v> vex;
for(vex[i]=0; i < vex.size; i++){
    return vex;
}
}

GetAllEdges(e)
{
   vector<e> edg;
   for(vex[i]=0; i< edg.size; i++){
    return edg;
}
}

}

int main()
{
  return 0; }
```

Comment: Firstly, class definitions must end in `};`. Semicolon is required. You remembered in for `class Node` and `class Edge`, but for some reason completely forgot about it for `class Graph`. Secondly, what is `GetAllVertices(v)`??? Is it a function declaration? If so, where is its return type? And why is its definition stuffed inside the `Graph `s constructor definition? Thirdly, where is the declaration of `i`?

Comment: `Graph` has `}`s strewn around randomly.

Comment: Your methods in `Graph` are missing return types (except the constructor).

Comment: Your methods in `Graph` are missing parameter types before the parameter.  An example:  `vector<v> GetAllVertices(unsigned int vertex_count)`.

Comment: Your `for` loops return for the first iteration and never get past the first iteration.

Comment: In `GetAllEdges`, you are accessing a variable `vex` which is not declared inside the method.  Methods can't access local variables in other methods.

Comment: Your `main` function doesn't make an instance (variable) of the `Graph` class.

Comment: You are using variable instances for the vector type.  Reread the syntax for a `std::vector`.  You probably want `vector<Node<T> >` or `vector<Node<T> *>`.

Comment: You don't need to use the `new` operator.  Try declaring a variable and using the `vector::push_back()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There really is value in keeping code pretty (esp. standardized indentation).  It will help you find these mismatched brace issues easier.

It's much easier if you write pretty code to start, but you can use your editor to help. If your editor doesn't have a code reformatter feature, think about getting another editor.   Most editors will also have a find matching brace feature.  If you put the cursor on a brace, parenthesis, or bracket it the brace match key will find the corresponding open or close and you can verify if this is what you expect.